# XML data getting with php (just images not product_id)

Tags: php, xml

Hi i have an xml data like this

```
<Product>
<ProductID>13078</ProductID>
<image1>
image_url
</image1>
<image2>
image_url
</image2>
<image3>
image_url
</image3>
</Product>
```

i want to access images
please help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `SimpleXMLElement`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, "SimpleXMLElement");
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
unset($array['ProductID']); // You don't want 'ProductID' then You can remove it using unset().
$i=1;
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    echo $array['image'.$i]; // Here you can get all images in one echo
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: i want to access all images with one echo

Comment: because i will use foreach for loop them

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    print_r($xml);
}
```

you will get a result array

or else if you have XML string use this function

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
```

hope this will help you

Your Solution:

```
    $string = '<Product>
<ProductID>13078</ProductID>
<image1>
image_url
</image1>
<image2>
image_url
</image2>
<image3>
image_url
</image3>
</Product>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo $xml->image1;
```

Comment: i want to access just images

Comment: Please can you check my answer @Volkan